# uBlock - hide any element that contains text with a given word?

Tags: ublock, ublock-origin

Is it possible to write a custom filter rule so that any `div`, `span` or `p` and its children are hidden when there is a specific word in the text part, i.e. `Trump`?

For example, I have this structure

```
<div>
  <a class="..." href="...">Donald Trump said blablabla.</a>
</div>
```

I tried this, but it has no effect:

```
##div>a:has-text(Trump)
```

Answer (score 47):

Try `##div>a:has-text(/Trump/)`

Comment: Why? Could you give explanation?

Comment: That's the proposed CSS4 syntax, and many adblockers have already implemented it. uBlock Origin has it, for example.

Comment: Works for me. I got rid of the `Not interested` option on YouTube videos. Once in a while, when clicking the hamburger menu on a video(`...`), I'd accidentally click the first option labeled `Not Interested`. I usually go into the menu to only add to my `Watch later` playlist.
Sadly, the only way to undo `Not interested` is to completely wipe all your submissions of `Not Interested`.... which is extremely frustrating when I'm trying to tailor the YouTube suggestions for me.

This is what I used: 
`www.youtube.com##.ytd-menu-service-item-renderer:has-text(Not interested)`

Comment: Why is RegEx needed? Shouldn't OP's non-regex code work?

Answer (score 10):

`:has-text()` is a [procedural cosmetic filter](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Procedural-cosmetic-filters). Those "must always be specific, i.e. prefixed with the hostname of the site(s) on which they are meant to apply."

Procedural cosmetic filters are powerful but to be avoided if possible as they can slow down site loading (JavaScript has to be inserted and visit lots of nodes).

If you still want it, it should look like this:

```
example.com,domain.com,anotherexample.com##div>a:has-text(Trump)
```

---

You [can change that behaviour](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Advanced-settings#allowgenericproceduralfilters) so a non-specific procedural cosmetic filter like `##div>a:has-text(Trump)` will work, but it is **absolutely not recommended**. It will slow down your browser on every page and there's the possibility that errors in external filterlists will go free-turning and produce lots of false positives / overblocking.

You can find that option buried in

1. uBO Dashboard
2. Settings
3. Check "I am an advanced user"
4. Read and understand the warnings
5. Click the gears
6. Change "allowGenericProceduralFilters" to `true`
7. Click "Apply changes"

p.s.: Forward slashes like `:has-text(/Target words/)`are *not* needed. If you use them, the expression inside will be evaluated as [RegEx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) which will cause even more workload.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it doesn't necessarily need to visit a lot of nodes - just make your selector (everything before :has-text) nice and specific.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `has-text` selector only works when a top level domain is given. So the following works, for example, but only on the Guardian website:

```
theguardian.com##.fc-item__container:has-text(Trump)
```